# Updating a figure with multiple subplots during a loop where subplot must contains image/matrix with colorbar

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to carry out a simulation where I perform calculation over some matrices which gets updated over the loop. Now I want to see their evolution over time so I plotted them with respective colorbars within the loop.
All was ok till I didn't use the colorbar. As soon as I used colorbar the subplots stopped displaying. I tried several option and one possibility was to omit plt.clf(). It seems to work for small number of iteration, however without it the simulation gets slow as the fig variable kept storing images (see len(plt.gca().images). I am looking for a solution of above problem without slowing down execution speed.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time

def mysubplots(ax,mat,title):
    im00 = ax.imshow(mat);
    ax.set_title(title);
    cax = plt.colorbar(im00, ax=ax);
    return cax

(n,m) = (200,200)
A = np.random.random((n,m))
B = np.random.random((n,m))
C = np.random.random((n,m))

plt.close()
fig,ax = plt.subplots(2,2, sharex=True, sharey=True,figsize=(5,5))
caxa = mysubplots(ax[0,0], A, 'A')
caxb = mysubplots(ax[0,1], B, 'B')
caxc = mysubplots(ax[1,0], C, 'C')
                      
for i in range(500):
    A = i*np.random.random((n,m))
    B = i*np.random.random((n,m))
    C = i*np.random.random((n,m))
       
    caxa.remove()
    caxb.remove()
    caxc.remove()
    plt.clf()
    
    caxa = mysubplots(ax[0,0], A, 'A')
    caxb = mysubplots(ax[0,1], B, 'B')
    caxc = mysubplots(ax[1,0], C, 'C')
    plt.suptitle(f'Iteration {i}')
        
    fig.canvas.draw()
    fig.canvas.flush_events()
    time.sleep(.1)
```

PS: I changed the scale of the data so that it increases loop progress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some problems in your code, in terms of how you want to update the figure: `plt.clf() --> fig.canvas.draw()` only works if you do not have subplots. `plt.clf()` clears the whole figure, which includes deleting the definition of the subplots and the axes.

A more viable approach would be clearing the content of the axis itself, using `ax.cla()`.

You can use the following code to do what you want:

```
import numpy as np
%matplotlib notebook
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time


(n,m) = (200,200)
A = np.random.random((n,m))
B = np.random.random((n,m))
C = np.random.random((n,m))

def update_subplot(ax, data, title, i, cmap='viridis'):
    ax.cla()
    im = ax.imshow(data)
    if i == 0:
        plt.colorbar(im, ax = ax)
    ax.set_title(title)
    
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 2, sharex=True, sharey=True,figsize=(8,8))

for i in range(500):
    
    A = np.random.random((n,m))
    B = np.random.random((n,m))
    C = np.random.random((n,m))
    
    update_subplot(ax[0,0], A, "A", i)
    update_subplot(ax[0,1], B, "B", i)
    update_subplot(ax[1,0], C, "C", i)
    
    plt.suptitle(f'Iteration {i}')
    fig.canvas.draw()
    time.sleep(.1)
```

One thing to consider in this approach: colorbar is not updated, it is only drawn once when `i == 0`. To update the colorbar as well, try assigning the colorbar and then using `cbar.remove()` to delete it if it exists

**V2.0:** added update of colorbar

So as I mentioned before, the colorbar would not be updated, since it is only done once. In the following code, the function checks if the colorbar exists, if so, it deletes it and then plots it again. This ensures that you don't have 500 colorbars at the end of the for loop.

```
(n,m) = (200,200)

def update_subplot(ax, data, title, cbar, cmap='viridis'):
    ax.cla()
    im = ax.imshow(data)
    if cbar is None:
        cbar = plt.colorbar(im, ax=ax)
    else:
        cbar.remove()
        cbar = plt.colorbar(im, ax=ax)
    ax.set_title(title)
    return cbar
    
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 2, sharex=True, sharey=True,figsize=(8,8))
cbar00 = None
cbar01 = None
cbar10 = None

for i in range(10):
    
    A = np.random.random((n,m))*i
    B = np.random.random((n,m))*i
    C = np.random.random((n,m))*i
    
    cbar00 = update_subplot(ax[0,0], A, "A", cbar00)
    cbar01 = update_subplot(ax[0,1], B, "B", cbar01)
    cbar10 = update_subplot(ax[1,0], C, "C", cbar10)
    
    plt.suptitle(f'Iteration {i}')
    fig.canvas.draw()
    time.sleep(.1)
```

Here is an animation of the above code, where I multiplied ABC with i, such that it is always increasing:

[image: Animation]

**V3.0**: how to get it to work in spyder

Instead of using the notebook backend, tk can be used for the matplotlib library. Furthermore, it's necessary to flush events after canvas.draw:

```
import numpy as np
%matplotlib tk
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time

(n,m) = (200,200)

def update_subplot(ax, data, title, cbar, cmap='viridis'):
ax.cla()
im = ax.imshow(data)
if cbar is None:
cbar = plt.colorbar(im, ax=ax)
else:
cbar.remove()
cbar = plt.colorbar(im, ax=ax)
ax.set_title(title)
return cbar

fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 2, sharex=True, sharey=True,figsize=(8,8))
cbar00 = None
cbar01 = None
cbar10 = None

for i in range(10):

A = np.random.random((n,m))*i
B = np.random.random((n,m))*i
C = np.random.random((n,m))*i

cbar00 = update_subplot(ax[0,0], A, "A", cbar00)
cbar01 = update_subplot(ax[0,1], B, "B", cbar01)
cbar10 = update_subplot(ax[1,0], C, "C", cbar10)

plt.suptitle(f'Iteration {i}')
fig.canvas.draw()
fig.canvas.flush_events()
time.sleep(.1)
```

Still the command window running left

**V4.0**: running from a command window (disclaimer: I am running it from linux)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time


(n,m) = (200,200)

def update_subplot(ax, data, title, cbar, cmap='viridis'):
    ax.cla()
    im = ax.imshow(data)
    if cbar is None:
        cbar = plt.colorbar(im, ax=ax)
    else:
        cbar.remove()
        cbar = plt.colorbar(im, ax=ax)
    ax.set_title(title)
    return cbar
    
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 2, sharex=True, sharey=True,figsize=(8,8))
cbar00 = None
cbar01 = None
cbar10 = None

for i in range(100):
    print(i)
    A = np.random.random((n,m))*i
    B = np.random.random((n,m))*i
    C = np.random.random((n,m))*i
    
    cbar00 = update_subplot(ax[0,0], A, "A", cbar00)
    cbar01 = update_subplot(ax[0,1], B, "B", cbar01)
    cbar10 = update_subplot(ax[1,0], C, "C", cbar10)
    
    plt.suptitle(f'Iteration {i}')
    plt.pause(0.1)
```

Here, the fig methods did not really work for me, and the backend choice did not have an effect on displaying the images. `plt.pause()` did the trick though.

Comment: This doesn't seem to working on my computer as intended. I ran your code through the terminal, as well as using Spyder but the figure window remains black.

Comment: did you remove the %matplotlib notebook line?

Comment: Yes. When I ran the script with "%matplotlib" notebook line, it produced an error. BTW I just added "fig.canvas.flush_events()" command after "fig.canvas.draw()"  and it is working now. Thanks.

Comment: My snippet worked in jupyter in case you ever want to do that there. Now I learned from you how to do it in spyder as well :D Thanks!

Comment: I just realized the colorbars are not updating at all. For the above example it worked because the random numbers were always limited between (0,1). For a simulation the range is dynamic. Is there any way to fix that?

Comment: @Amartya yeah I expected that, let me edit the code with an updating colorbar... As I said, it should be as simple as assigning the colorbar and passing it to the function to see if it exists, then deleting if so, since doing a colorbar each time will add another one and not update it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256418/discussion-between-tino-d-and-amartya).